# split file to multiple files based on file size sas

Tags: sas

I would like to know how to split large file to multiple files based on a certain file size. I'm using the File statement as it will also be exported as a delimited text file.

Any thoughts on how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code i used to export a flat file to a delimited text file:

```
    data _null_;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      %let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */                                                                                                                                                                                          
      %let _EFIREC_ = 0; /* clear export record count macro variable */    

   file "C:\test\file..txt" delimiter=';' DSD DROPOVER lrecl=32767 ENCODING="UTF-8";
```

With a header record of ±300 bytes, 4MB can fit 7.060 records where each field in each record is filled to the maximum length (594 bytes).
I think the first run will load up to 7.000 records.

Comment: Are you talking file size as in MB or number of rows?

Comment: yes, a maximum of 4mb per file.

Comment: You need more information in the question.  At _minimum_ include a sample dataset and sample data step output.

Comment: why does splitting single file into multiple file be solved using SAS. Can't we use os utilities to solve the problem. Like in linux you can use SPLIT command to do similar thing. I think on mainframe we can also do similar thing using IDCAMS(based on no. of records..not sure about size here) and on windows probably hjsplit could be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a quick & dirty way of estimating a safe limit:

- run a proc contents
- find out the length of each record (stored in SAS formats)
- add a safety margin of 30% for fields that will be longer when written out to a flat file. (e.g., numerics have a default SAS length of 8 bytes but could be written out as 20 or more, depending on what formats are used, if any)
- divide 4mb by the estimated row length
- use a row counter to chunk the large file into output files that will fit within your 4mb limit